# Evaluate: $\lim_{x\to \infty} (\sqrt {x-a} - \sqrt {bx})$

Tags: calculus, limits

Evaluate: $\lim_{x\to \infty} (\sqrt {x-a} - \sqrt {bx})$.

......
$$\lim_{x\to \infty} (\sqrt {x-a} - \sqrt {bx})$$
It takes $\infty - \infty $ form when $x=\infty $.
Now,
$$=\lim_{x\to \infty } (\sqrt {x-a} - \sqrt {bx})\times \dfrac {\sqrt {x-a}+\sqrt {bx}}{\sqrt {x-a}+\sqrt {bx}}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to \infty } \dfrac {x-a-bx}{\sqrt {x-a}+\sqrt {bx}}$$

Comment: Now divide the numerator & the denominator by $x$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee, why should this division be done? And, why by $x$?

Comment: If $b=1$ then the limit is $0$. Otherwise divide the numerator and the denominator by $ \sqrt x$ to get rid of $\frac {\infty} {\infty}$

Comment: @EugenCovaci, Could you please elaborate? I didn't understand.

Comment: @Ofek Gillon gave you a complete answer.

Answer (score 3):

Take $\sqrt{x}$ out to get:

$$L=\lim_\limits{x\to\infty} \sqrt{x}\left(\sqrt{1-\frac{a}{x}}-\sqrt{b}\right)=\lim_\limits{x\to\infty} \sqrt{x}\left(1-\sqrt{b}\right).$$

If $b=1$, $L=0$.

If $b>1$, $L=-\infty$.

If $0\le b<1$, $L=+\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

I'll add to Eugen's comment:

If $b=1$ then we have:
$$ \lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{-a}{\sqrt{x-a}+\sqrt{x}} = \frac{-a}{\infty} = 0$$
otherwise,
$$ \lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{(1-b)x-a}{\sqrt{x-a}+\sqrt{x}} =\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{(1-b)\sqrt{x} - \frac{a}{\sqrt{x}}}{\sqrt{1-\frac{a}{x}}+1} = \lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{(1-b)\sqrt{x}-0}{\sqrt{1-0}+1}=\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{1-b}{2}\sqrt{x}$$
Meaning that the answer will be $\pm \infty$ dependeing on $\operatorname{sign}(1-b)$

Comment: $\dfrac{(1-b)x-a}{\sqrt{x-a}+\sqrt{bx}}$.

Comment: Oh, yeah, I thought there was a $b$ only at the numerator. Well, the correct answer  is achieved by using the same principals :)